# Add CSS but keep inline style

Tags: javascript, css

What I'm doing wrong.

Need to add CSS with JavaScript but I have to keep all the inline styles.

In this case when user clicks h1 element, the color of the inline style needs to stay the same and just add new style from javascript.

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/59qfxwcu/

```
<h1 style="color: red;">Test</h1>
<h1 style="color: green;">Test</h1>

<script>
function some(){
    var element = document.querySelectorAll('h1');

      element.forEach(function(item){

        item.onclick = function(){
            var inlineCss = this.style;

                item.style.cssText = inlineCss + 'background: blue; font-size: 12px;';
          }

      });
}

some();

</script>
```

Comment: `this.style` is not a text , it is an object. You must use your debugger by yourself first

Comment: Why not `+=` instead of `=`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `style.background` and `style.fontSize` javascript properties:

```js
function some(el) {
  var element = document.querySelectorAll('h1');

  element.forEach(function(item) {

    item.onclick = function() {
      item.style.background = 'blue';  // Change the background of the element
      item.style.fontSize = '12px';    // Change the font-size of the element
    }

  });
}

some();
```

```html
<h1 style="color: red;">Test</h1>
<h1 style="color: green;">Test</h1>
```